# How to write session based sql queries in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have to add a condition if there is admin logged into system I want to show all records from members table but if its moderator logged into the system I just want to show moderator's own records from a member table.

Problem is I am not getting and having error like syntax error at line 1.

Query is:

```
$all_members = query("SELECT id
     CASE
      WHEN (SELECT * FROM " . _SB_ADMINS_ . " WHERE id = '" . $_SESSION['__SB_ADMIN_USER_ID__'] . "' AND type = 'admin' LIMIT 1)
      THEN (SELECT * FROM " . _SB_MEMBERS_ . " ORDER BY datetime DESC)
      WHEN (SELECT * FROM " . _SB_ADMINS_ . " WHERE id = '" . $_SESSION['__SB_ADMIN_USER_ID__'] . "' AND type = 'moderator' LIMIT 1)
      THEN (SELECT * FROM " . _SB_MEMBERS_ . " WHERE admin_id = '" . $_SESSION['__SB_ADMIN_USER_ID__'] . "' ORDER BY datetime DESC)
    END");
```

If its not a possibility so would it be like below?

```
if($_SESSION["__SB_ADMIN_USER_TYPE__"] == 'admin') {

     $all_members = query("SELECT * FROM " . _SB_MEMBERS_ . " ORDER BY datetime DESC");

    }elseif($_SESSION["__SB_ADMIN_USER_TYPE__"] == 'moderator'){

     $all_members = query("SELECT * FROM " . _SB_MEMBERS_ . " WHERE admin_id = '" . $_SESSION['__SB_ADMIN_USER_ID__'] . "' ORDER BY datetime DESC");      

 }
```

Edit: I added possible solution if its the last solution?

Comment: If I'm following along pretty well, you have your data in different tables. I would suggest you save your data in same table and add a column to hold roles <admin, members>. With that  you can query the data and use an if statement to check the roles of the logged in user

Comment: I have all records of members data in one table and saving admin_id in it that can be checked whether I want to show admin's members or mod's members. But I want to show all records for admin and least with mod.

Comment: Use prepared statements to avoid sql injection